# Drop event is not working in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm trying to simulate a drag and drop scenario in protractor. I can select the element and drag it to the point which i want but it does not perform the drop action

this is the code that i'm using to perform the drag and drop action

```
it('should drag and drop ', function(){
   browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

   element.all(by.repeater('associate in associates')).then(function(completeColumns){
     var startPointForDraging = completeColumns[0];
     var endPointForDraging = element(by.xpath("xpath_to_the_location"));
          browser.actions().dragAndDrop(startPointForDraging,endPointForDraging).perform();
   });

});
```

can someone give me an idea what i am missing here

Comment: Are you sure the locator used to locate `endPointForDraging` is correct and the element allows "dropping"?

Comment: yes it is correct when i run the test case visually i can see that the element is getting dragged to the location specified by the 'x-path'

Comment: What if you would try `browser.actions().mouseDown(startPointForDraging).mouseMove(endPointForDraging).mouseUp().perform();`?

Comment: Another thing to try: `browser.actions().mouseDown(startPointForDraging).mouseMove(endPointForDraging, {x: 10, y: 10})‌​.mouseUp().perform();` - basically trying to drop with an offset (not to the top left corner of the element).